# linear-expansion filter for image (2D array)

Tags: image-processing, filters, python

I am working in python analyzing 2D arrays and I am looking for a filter or some other routine that would provide a linear expansion of an region boundaries in a 2D array with binary regions (i.e. a black/white image).  For example given this star image:

[image: Unfiltered image]

I would like to apply a filter that expands a region's borders with a  radial, linear decrease from a maximal value (i.e. black) to the surrounding value.   Graphically represented as:

[image: Conceptual effect of filter]

So that the resulting image/array is something like:

[image]

Comment: I did not got your problem, by expansion do you mean you'd like to to enlarge the image (i.e. scale up)?

Comment: Hi MimSaad,  I do not want to change the values in the original region, but I want a bordering region that changes linearly towards the values in the surrounding region.  This is shown schematically in the middle figure of my post.

Comment: The linear constraint is the hard one. Mainly since it is 2D world so it should be linear in which direction? If you mean smooth, than any blur should do it.

Comment: How about not doing convolution at all, but simply sliding a window over the image and counting the Euclidean distance to the nearest «star» pixel?

Comment: Look for the distance transform. For example https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html or https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/distance.html#dip-EuclideanDistanceTransform-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL

Answer (score -1):

Simply resize the binarized image to a larger image but do not use any high order interpolation in resizing and instead use '**nearest neighbor**'interpolation technique. In MATLAB:

```
im2 = imresize(image, 10, 'nearest')
```

part of 10x expanded image:

[image]

and a raster of the image:

[image]

Comment: Hi MimSaad   Unfortunately that will not work because I need to retain the original scale of the array and the original dimensions/positions of the unfiltered regions of the array (image).